# Can you tracking which chrome extensions are installed in a browser in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, tracking

I am trying to track which chrome extensions are installed in a browser in Google Analytics. We are struggling with a specific company that provides a service that allows you to access illegally distributed content that is behind our paywall. I would like to see what % of visitors have this extension and is it a regional thing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's not possible to do this in general (it's a privacy concern, to reveal which extensions the user has installed) however, if you know the specific extension(s) which may cause the problem, you may be able to detect their presence by what side effects they cause on the page. But it would be sort of a cat-and-mouse game, where you would need to check if it works each time they update the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Google Analytics. An out of the box idea that occurred to me since we're on the Chrome Extensions tag anyway- your paywall could start enforcing that your users must have an extension(which you write) installed. Your paywalled site would use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) with your extension to check that it is present. As part of your message passing, your extension could use the [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API to give your site a list of other extensions installed, and your site could then choose to allow the user or not.

This is pretty skeevy/sketchy though, and ultimately there are ways around it, running a paywall is a bit of an arms race anyway.